# How to upload thousands of folders to firebase storage at once

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, unzip, gsutil

I have a client that needs to upload thousands of folders to firebase storage at one time.
I have tried uploading a .zip file, but can not figure out how to unzip it. I have followed every guide out there.

Is there a way to batch upload thousands of file folders to a google cloud storage bucket at one time?

Comment: You must upload each file. You can upload in parallel. Google Cloud Storage does not provide processing power to do things like unzipping files. Google published a CLI to upload files: **gsutil**.

Answer (score 3):

To add to John Hanley's comment:

> You must upload each file. You can upload in parallel. Google Cloud Storage does not provide processing power to do things like unzipping files. Google published a CLI to upload files: **gsutil**.

If you have a large number of files to transfer, you can perform a parallel multi-threaded/multi-processing copy using the top-level gsutil `-m` option :

`gsutil -m cp -r dir gs://my-bucket`

Additionally, in [Parallel Composite Upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#parallel-composite-uploads), gsutil can automatically use object composition to perform uploads in parallel for large, local files being uploaded to Cloud Storage. You can also check this documentation regarding [Uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads#uploads), that discusses size considerations in uploading, and further explanation of **Parallel Composite Uploads**.